# How to view the SQL statements participated in a deadlock using xml_deadlock_report?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I found that my database has (by default) xml_deadlock_report extended event is on. On my server logs, I have some found deadlock exception. The xp_readerrorlog does not show any deadlock information. How to grab the deadlock information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer,

```
SELECT CAST (
    REPLACE (
        REPLACE (
            XEventData.XEvent.value ('(data/value)[1]', 'varchar(max)'),
            '<victim-list>', '<deadlock><victim-list>'),
        '<process-list>', '</victim-list><process-list>')
    AS XML) AS DeadlockGraph
FROM (SELECT CAST (target_data AS XML) AS TargetData
    FROM sys.dm_xe_session_targets st
    JOIN sys.dm_xe_sessions s ON s.address = st.event_session_address
    WHERE [name] = 'system_health') AS Data
CROSS APPLY TargetData.nodes ('//RingBufferTarget/event') AS XEventData (XEvent)
    WHERE XEventData.XEvent.value('@name', 'varchar(4000)') = 'xml_deadlock_report';
```

Thanks to, [Deadlock graph from XEvents doesn't produce "good" XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817951/deadlock-graph-from-xevents-doesnt-produce-good-xml)